# How to set default value for Domain Class Values in Grails 2.2?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

In my Grails domain class I want to set default values which do persist in the database. I use mysql as database. I tried to do this:

```
class A {

   long someValue = 1
   long someOtherValue
   boolean someBool = true
   boolean someOtherBool

   static mapping = {
      someOtherValue defaultValue: 1
      someOtherBool defaultValue: true  
   }
}
```

But nothing works. There are no default values set in the database. What do I have to change  to get my default values being set correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are on Grails 2.2 above then you can use defaultValue. Look at Burt's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577459/how-can-i-set-default-value-in-grails-domain-class)
Try it, hope this helps:

```
Class A {
      Long someValue 
      Long someOtherValue

      Boolean someBool
      Boolean someOtherBool

     static mapping = {
        someOtherValue defaultValue: 1
        someOtherBool  defaultValue: true  
        ...
     } 

}
```

Comment: this is what I wrote as question. I use Grails 2.2.2 but it is not working.

Comment: This works for in 2.3.6 for all types but not for `Boolean`. I tried `defaultValue: 'true'` and `defaultValue: true`. But in the table is is filled with `null`. I have to use `Boolean mycolumn = Boolean.TRUE`

Comment: what is your database ?

Comment: Using grails 2.5, and mysql 5.6, it does not seem possible to set a database level defaultValue for a boolean nor a Boolean.  true, 'true', "true", 1, '1', "1", Boolean.TRUE - none of these work in the static mapping section.

Answer (score 2):

I found that for defaultValue to work with String properties, I needed to put double quotes around single quotes and for defaultValue to work for numeric properties, I needed to put double quotes around the number or the defaults wouldn't appear in the DDL. So, for instance:

```
static mapping = {
   myStringProperty defaultValue: "'Cash'"
   myIntProperty defaultValue: "0"
}
```

Also, as far as I can tell, default values do not work for properties that are enums.

Comment: Sadly, this does not work for booleans (which are BIT fields with length of 1).

Answer (score 2):

```
class A {

   long someValue
   long someOtherValue
   boolean someBool = Boolean.TRUE
   boolean someOtherBool = Boolean.TRUE

   static mapping = {
      someValue defaultValue: '1'
      someOtherValue defaultValue: '1'
   }
}
```

This will work, tested in 2.2.3.

Comment: I also have to set boolean columns like this in 2.3.6 Setting defaultValue for a boolean columnn in the mappings does not work.

Comment: The above does not work for us in grails 2.5 and mysql for booleans, always gives no default.

Comment: Also does not work in MySQL in Grails 3.3  `defaultValue: false`  or `defaultValue:"'false'"` or `defaultValue: 'false'`